# Clear the input box after submitting the form in Angular 4

Tags: html, forms, angular, node-modules

I want to clear the input box after submitting the form.

this is my app.component.ts file:

```
todos: string[];

addTodo(todo)
{
   this.todos.push(todo);
   return false;
}
```

this is my app.component.html file

```
<form (submit)="addTodo(todo.value)">
<input type="text" #todo>
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let todo of todos">{{todo}}</li>
</ul>
```

When I fill a todo in my input box, and press enter or return key on my keyboard it should automatically clear my input box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `app.component.ts` file change the follwing code :

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
export class AppComponent {

   @ViewChild("todo") el : ElementRef
   addTodo(todo)
   {
       this.todos.push(todo);
       this.el.nativeElement.value = "";
       return false;
   }
}
```

By using this,after submitting the form textbox value will be cleared.

Hope, it wil help!

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use data binding.

The HTML would then look like this:

```
<form (submit)="addTodo(todo.value)">
<input type="text" #todo [(ngModel)]="currentToDo" name="todo">
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let todo of todos">{{todo}}</li>
</ul>
```

Be sure to pull in the FormsModule now that we are using two-way binding.

The class would look like this.

```
todos: string[];
currentTodo: string

addTodo(todo)
{
   this.todos.push(todo);
   this.currentTodo = '';
   return false;
}
```

You could even use currentToDo in the addTodo function instead of passing it in:

```
todos: string[];
currentTodo: string

addTodo()
{
   this.todos.push(this.currentTodo);
   currentTodo = '';
   return false;
}
```

Here is the change to your AppModule that you'll need for two-way binding:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank for your contribution, I tried your code but its popping an error, like this **Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'**

Comment: Did you see my note: `Be sure to pull in the FormsModule now that we are using two-way binding.` The message you are seeing is because you didn't pull FormsModule in to your AppModule. I'll post that code as well.

Comment: Yeah I imported that FormsModule in app.module.ts, besides that  we should also include **name** attribute in ngModule when we use input field, like below,
      `<input [(ngModel)]="firstname" name="firstname">`

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks for catching that. I'll fix my code above in case anyone else looks at it.